# Конвертировать Scala в Java или как ее использовать в разработке под Android?

Tags: java, android-sdk, android-studio, android, scala

Нашел некую работу на github больше половины кода в непонятном Scala, вопрос можно ли эту Скалу превратить в Яву для привычного мне вида.
А то Java в Scala конвертировать можно - http://javatoscala.com/

И еще если Андроид проект скомпилировать, а потом попытаться расковырять вид будет уже более привычный к Java или все-же таже Скала.

Ну и если использовать scala, как отобразиться в будущем на проекте, будет вес меньше или скорость больше ?

Comment: "_будет вес меньше или скорость больше_": Scala, как и все высокоуровневые языки, даёт преимущество не в скорости/размере компилята (за этим вам нужно обращаться в сторону более низкоуровневых языков). Преимущество здесь в выразительной силе языка и облегчении программирования сложных конструкций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Конвертить Scala в Java идея довольно безумная т.к. в Java нет очень многих конструкций Scala такий как `case class`, `match` и многих других, это раздует существующий код в 2-3 раза, если не больше. Более того он станет абсолютно не читаемым, страшно представить во что развернётся, например, ковариантный дженерик. Ну и готовьтесь к тому что вам придётся в дальнейшем, модифицируя этот код, работать со Scala коллекциями(на Java это будет ОЧЕНЬ не приятно) и тянуть за собой Scala библиотеки(они довольно массивные).
2. Scala в проекте, в сравнение с Java, уменьшит кол-во строк кода в несколько раз(тупая конвертация с использование javatoscala уже существенно сократит код), ну и, имхо, на Scala гораздо приятнее писать, там функциональное программирование и другие Scala плюшки(очень рекомендую почитать какую-нибудь статейку на эту тему). Но есть и минусы, в скорости вы скорее всего не выиграете, а может и проиграете, программы в ФП стиле будут работать чуть дольше(можно критичные участки кода переписать в ООП стиле и производительность будет как в Java), а размер apk на выходе скорее всего будет больше, как раз за счёт массивной стандартной библиотеки языка, но тут должен придти на помощь ProGuard, но практика показывает, что apk всё-равно будет чуть больше, чем если бы приложение было написано на Java.

Answer (score 2):

Scala компилится в Java код, так то отвечая на последний вопрос, работать они будут одинаково (ну конечно есть исключения, но сейчас не об этом).

Вы можете декомпилировать код и он будет на Java.

А так, есть отличный проект [scaloid](https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid) для разработки Android приложений на Scala. Имхо, разберитесь со Scala, она не такая и сложная, и Вы проапгрейдитесь и приложение будет работать. А то декомпилить класс и копировать его в исходники на костыль похоже.

Comment: Scala компилируется не в Java код, а в байткод JVM.

Comment: Пардон, не совсем точно написал:)

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически, вы можете получить Java код. Да, для этого придется взять jar-файлы, скормить любому декомпилятору поддерживающему хотя бы Java 6. И вы получите на выходе Java код. Устроит ли вас этот код? Дело в том что, код, который вы получите при трансляции, понятным можно будет назвать с большим трудом. Подробную инструкцию о том как это сделать вы можете найти [здесь](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-to-decompiled-java-source-code-classes). Больше о процессе декомпиляции вы можете узнать [здесь](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-disassemble-decompile-scala-source-code-javap-scalac-jad)

Answer (score 0):

Scala предоставляет мощный инструмент для написания кода, но ни вес (вероятно, т.к. scala код все равно преобразуется в байт-код), ни скорость не будут лучше: более того, в некоторых случаях скорость Scala на порядок (в 10 раз) хуже Java, например, при сортировке списков (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588615/scala-collection-sorted-sortwith-and-sortby-performance). Даже при использовании обычных массивов будет потеря в скорости из-за оберток. Как уже написано раньше, использовать Scala в Java проекте не очень удобно (в отличии от использования Java в Scala). При компиляции под Android могут возникнуть дополнительные проблемы, впрочем, решаемые.